# LazyVGrid produces different vertical spacing with different custom heights

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, lazyvgrid

I have LazyVGrid and inside I have a custom view that can changes it's height based on the image ratio the description etc ... the grid is sizing the view correctly but then the vertical spacing between each view varies based on the size of the view like in the image. [image: Wong vertical sizing] I want the vertical spacing always remains at 8 point. like in this image the third cell must be attached to the first one with 8 points of spacing. I copied my code here I have given it already a spacing attribute. Also I tried to put height as infinity for the custom view but it didn't work. How Can I have a fixed vertical spacing between grid Items?

```
import SwiftUI

public struct NewsFeedView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = NewsViewModel()
    
    let columns: [GridItem] = [
        GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 8),
        GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 8)
    ]
    
    public var body: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: columns, alignment: .leading, spacing: 8.0) {
            
            ForEach(viewModel.newsItems) { newsItem in
                NewsCell(newsItem: newsItem)
                    .frame(minHeight: 100, maxHeight: .infinity)
            }
        }
        .padding(16)
    }
}

public struct NewsCell: View {
    @ObservedObject var newsItem: NewsItemViewModel

    public var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
            Image(systemName: "heart")          //.scaledToFit()
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(CGFloat(newsItem.imageAspectRatio), contentMode: .fit)
                .background(Color.black)

            Text(newsItem.title)
                .lineLimit(nil)
                .font(.headline)

            Text(newsItem.subtitle)
                .lineLimit(nil)
                .font(.subheadline)
                .foregroundColor(.gray)

            Text(newsItem.description)
                .lineLimit(nil)
                .foregroundColor(.black)

            if !newsItem.tags.isEmpty {
                Divider()
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 4) {
                    ForEach(newsItem.tags) { tag in
                        Text(tag.label)
                            .font(.footnote)
                            .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        .padding()
        .background(Color.white)
        .overlay(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                .stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1)
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say *the third cell must be attached to the first one with 8 points of spacing*, do you mean, there should be a gap of only 8pt between the cell with **Title 1** and the cell below it? This would mean, the third cell is not aligned in any way with the fourth cell (the cell below **Title 2**), right? So in fact, it sounds like you don't want a grid at all, you want two vertical stacks that are adjacent to each other.

Comment: @BenzyNeez yes exactly, so it is wrong to use grid? this is possible with UICollectionView. is there anything similar to that in swiftUI that can achieve the same goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a grid, both the rows and the columns are always aligned. Based on your answer to my comment, it sounds like you don't want row alignment. That means, you don't want a grid.

Try using an `HStack` as the container for two `LazyVStack` instead:

```swift
HStack(spacing: 8) {
    LazyVStack(spacing: 8) {
        // ...
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)

    LazyVStack(spacing: 8) {
        // ...
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
}
```

However, you will have to manage the distribution of items between the two stacks yourself.